# loading events for fullCalendar in nodes with jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fullcalendar

I was able to implement fullCalendar in nodeJS with jade and Express and it loads the calendar. When rendering the jade file, I am sending an array with events.
How can I load the events in the calendar in the jade template?
Jade file
extends ../../layouts/planninglayout

block content

```
script.
    var events =  [
        {
            title  : 'event3',
            start  : '2014-03-3 12:30:00',
            end  : '2014-03-3 16:30:00',
            allDay : false // will make the time show
        }
        ]

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            eventSources:events
        });
#calendar
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding events from an array you should not be using `eventSources`, this is for defining event feeds. You should be using `events` instead.

Your revised code should look something like this...

```
script.
    var events =  [
        {
            title: 'event3',
            start: '2014-03-3 12:30:00',
            end: '2014-03-3 16:30:00',
            allDay: false // will make the time show
        }
    ];

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events : events
    });
```

For full details, see documentation on adding events as an array [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/)

**UPDATE: Here's the exact code I have working in my test project**

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bower_components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css')
    body
        #calendar

        script(type='text/javascript', src='/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/bower_components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js')
        script.
            var events =  [
                {
                    title: 'event3',
                    start: '2014-03-03 12:30:00',
                    end: '2014-03-03 16:30:00',
                    allDay: false // will make the time show
                }
            ];
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                events: events
            });
```

Comment: I have tried changing the code as shown but it is still nog loading any events from the arrayextends ../../layouts/planninglayout


block content


 script.
  var events =  [
   {
    title  : 'event3',
    start  : '2014/03/16 10:30:00',
    end  : '2014/03/16 11:30:00',
    allDay : false // will make the time show
   }
   ]

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events:events
   });
 #calendar

Comment: Are you getting an errors? I have your exact example working in my own test project, works fine.

Comment: Jonathan, I don't get any error? I'm using nodeJS and Jade the calendar is rendered correctly and I have added an ClickEvent that also fires as in the samples. Might is be related to the date format in the events array and the configuration in the JS files? Do you have a simple running nodeJS with Jade sample? I'm not very familiair with JQuery stuff

Comment: Yes I have a test project I setup specifically to test this problem.  It is Node.js, Express.js with Jade template engine which is a setup I use extensively.  I'll update the answer with the full Jade view file which is all I changed from the default Express project.

Comment: Can you share that test project, so I can check what I am doing wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49872/discussion-between-peter-van-de-put-and-jonathan-miles)